# "Macaroni and cheese (is/are) on the lunch menu"

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

Is the sentence "“Macaroni and cheese is on the lunch menu.” correct?
I mean there 'is' is used as verb because two item means one unit. Or 'are' will be used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Is* is appropriate here, since "macaroni and cheese" refers to a single menu item, ordered as a unit.  A similar pair might be "spaghetti and meatballs."

Two completely separate items would use *are*.  For example, "Steak and chicken are on the menu."

Other options for a meal might use either verb, depending on how they are being discussed.

**Lunch Menu**
1. Hamburger and Fries
2. Fish and Chips

> A hamburger and fries are on the menu.
>   A hamburger and fries is one option from the menu.

In the second sentence, the message is set up to emphasize that "hamburger and fries" are a single item with multiple parts.

Fish and chips would be closer to macaroni and cheese in the US, as we don't refer to this style of fried potatoes as chips except in this context, when paired with fried, battered white fish.  Because these are grouped, you'd be more likely to hear someone say, "Fish and chips is on the menu" even though it would entirely appropriate to order them separately.  "Fish and chips are on the menu" would also be entirely acceptable.

Comment: The "lamb chops" might be a little confusing because it looks plural. I might use "Steak and fish are on the menu." Some folks also say "A hamburger _with_ fries is on the menu" to distinguish it from two separate menu items.

Comment: @Colleen I started with "steak and salmon" and changed it because it sounded like surf and turf.  :-)  Good point though.

Answer (score 0):

That sentence sounds clumsy to my feeling. I would prefer There's (the dish) macaroni and cheese on the menu.